# Filtering by multiple properties + sorting - how it should be done

Tags: .net, filtering

I created a way for filtering my resource by multiple parameters. I had also implemented sorting here. It is working, i just need to specify properties by which I can filter and sort manually. Is there any easier way to achieve same result, without such complex code?
Example api url is: localhost/api/supply-order-details?filters=name-eq-something,secondparameter-in-someth
etc.

```
 public async Task<SupplyOrderDetailResponse> Handle(SupplyOrderDetailsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IQueryable<SupplyOrderDetail> query = _db.SupplyOrderDetails
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(m => m.StatusId != 0);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.SearchTerm))
    {
        List<string> propertiesToFilter = request.SearchTerm.Split(',').ToList();
        foreach (string propertyToFilter in propertiesToFilter)
        {
            query = query.Where(GetFiltering(propertyToFilter));
        }
    }

    query = request.SortOrder?.ToLower() == "desc"
        ? query.OrderByDescending(GetSortProperty(request))
        : query = query.OrderBy(GetSortProperty(request));

    List<SupplyOrderDetailDto> result = await query
    .ProjectToDto()
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    SupplyOrderDetailResponse toReturn = new()
    {
        SupplyOrderDetails = result
    };

    return toReturn;
}

private static Expression<Func<SupplyOrderDetail, object>> GetSortProperty(SupplyOrderDetailsQuery request)
{

    return request.SortColumn?.ToLower() switch
    {
        "created" => m => m.Created,
        "createdby" => m => m.CreatedBy,
        "supplyorderheadernr" => m => m.SupplyOrderHeader.Nr,
        "materialname" => m => m.Material.Name,
        "materialsap" => m => m.Material.Sap!,
        "containset" => m => m.ContainSet,
        "containsetmainmaterial" => m => m.ContainSetMainMaterial,
        "materialmaterialtype" => m => m.Material.MaterialType,
        "quantity" => m => m.Quantity,
        "quantityinstalled" => m => m.QuantityInstalled!,
        "recipeversionname" => m => m.RecipeVersion!.Name!,
        "recipeversionversion" => m => m.RecipeVersion!.Version!,
        _ => m => m.Created
    };
}

private static Expression<Func<SupplyOrderDetail, bool>> GetFiltering(string propertyToFilter)
{
    (string property, string op, string value) = FilteringHelper.ParseFilterQuery(propertyToFilter);

    return property.ToLower() switch
    {
        "id" => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.Id, op, value),
        "createdby" => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.CreatedBy, op, value),
        "supplyorderheadernr" => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.SupplyOrderHeader.Nr, op, value),
        "supplyorderheaderid" => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.SupplyOrderHeader.Id, op, value),
        "materialname" => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.Material.Name, op, value),
        "materialsap" => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.Material!.Sap!, op, value),
        "containset" => FilteringHelper.CompareNumber<SupplyOrderDetail, bool>(m => m.ContainSet, op, bool.Parse(value)),
        "containsetmainmaterial" => FilteringHelper.CompareNumber<SupplyOrderDetail, bool>(m => m.ContainSetMainMaterial, op, bool.Parse(value)),
        "materialmaterialtype" => FilteringHelper.CompareEnum<SupplyOrderDetail, MaterialTypes>(m => m.Material.MaterialType, op, value),
        "quantity" => FilteringHelper.CompareNumber<SupplyOrderDetail, int>(m => m.Quantity, op, int.Parse(value)),
        "quantityinstalled" => FilteringHelper.CompareNumber<SupplyOrderDetail, int?>(m => m.QuantityInstalled, op, NullableHelpers.ToNullableInt(value)),
        "recipeversionname" => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.RecipeVersion!.Name!, op, value),
        "recipeversionversion" => FilteringHelper.CompareNumber<SupplyOrderDetail, int?>(m => m.RecipeVersion!.Version, op, NullableHelpers.ToNullableInt(value)),
        _ => FilteringHelper.CompareString<SupplyOrderDetail>(m => m.Id, op, value)
    };
}
public static class FilteringHelper
{
    public static (string property, string op, string value) ParseFilterQuery(string filterQuery)
    {
        var parts = filterQuery.Split('-',3);
        if (parts.Length == 3)
        {
            return (parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
        }
        return ("", "", "");
    }
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> CompareString<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, string>> property, string op, string value)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = property.Parameters[0];
        Expression body = property.Body;

        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(value);

        // Use reflection to get the Contains and Equals methods for strings
        var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var equalsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });

        // Check the op and create the corresponding expression
        switch (op.ToLower())
        {
            case "in":
                // Create an expression for property.Contains(value)
                var containsExpression = Expression.Call(body, containsMethod!, constant);
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(containsExpression, parameter);
            case "nin":
                // Create an expression for !property.Contains(value)
                var notContainsExpression = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(body, containsMethod!, constant));
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(notContainsExpression, parameter);
            default:
                var equalsExpression = Expression.Call(body, equalsMethod!, constant);
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(equalsExpression, parameter);
        }
    }
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> CompareNumber<TSource, TResponse>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResponse>> property, string op, TResponse value)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = property.Parameters[0];
        Expression body = property.Body;

        BinaryExpression comparison = op.ToLower() switch
        {
            "gt" => Expression.GreaterThan(body, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), body.Type)),
            "lt" => Expression.LessThan(body, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), body.Type)),
            "gte" => Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(body, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), body.Type)),
            "lte" => Expression.LessThanOrEqual(body, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), body.Type)),
            "neq" => Expression.NotEqual(body, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), body.Type)),
            _ => Expression.Equal(body, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), body.Type))
        };
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> CompareEnum<TSource, TResponse>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResponse>> property, string op, string value)
        where TResponse : struct
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse(value, out TResponse enumValue))
        {
            return CompareNumber(property, op, enumValue);
        }
        return _ => true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The complexity to me looks like it has more to do with you writing a general purpose query API involving query parameter parsing and trying to cover a large number of cases than *anything* to do with LINQ.  Suggestions on refactoring are considered off topic